# Looking for tips in firewall app creation

Tags: security

I'm trying to create a VERY simple firewall. For basically my own educational purposes, since I only know how to program in dos batch, if you can call that programming. I have a lot of computer experience, but no classic coding knowledge. Google pointed me at visual templates studio so I downloaded that and visual studio 2017 community. And found myself completly confused. I'm scared to click stuff :)

Anyway this is the idea:

First part of program is checking if it is in startup folder. If it is, it should start itself from there. If not, it should copy itself there and start itself. I beleive shortcut to that folder is shell:startup I have no idea about best practices, and don't care about them, this is only for me to get educated.

Second part is blocking all possible protocols on all possible network adapters (hidden, merged, bluetooth, don't care, all of them). After this part executes, a wireshark check should be mute. Absolutely nothing. Zip. Nada traffic.

Third part is having a taskbar icon and if clicked opening a window where I could add some simple exceptions. TCP+UDP ports incoming or outgoing or both.

It should be a dead silent app. No notifications of any kind. Mute.

So, if anyone has any tips to get me started in the right direction, I'd be gratefull. I'm still learning what buttons do in visual studio :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an appropriate project for your current skill level.

However, if you want to attempt it anyway, you will want to acquaint yourself with the [Windows Firewall with Advanced Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff956124(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

Note that using this API *will not*  make network sniffer tools like Wireshark report no activity, as 1) these tools observe traffic before firewall rules are applied; and 2) some network traffic, like ARP and DHCP, is required to join a network at all.

Comment: I just need some kind of a skeleton to work with. I'm not young anymore, and my capacity to learn is not what it used to be. I don't feel capable of learning a programming language from zero, but I do feel capable of editing a piece of already written code. If I see it, I think I may understand how it works, and make appropriate changes. That's how I made AI script for infinty engine games which is now published on their developer forum, and some other stuff aswell. I feel capable of clicking stuff and dismantling something already built, and imrpoving it, but not building it from tabula rasa.